# Unable to set group id in spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am unable to set group id in Spring cloud stream kafka consumer config using below :-

```
spring.cloud.stream.default-binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=${kafka.bootstrap.servers}
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.INPUT.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.INPUT.destination=datapipeline.ingestion.decision.topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.INPUT.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.INPUT.group=input-group-1
```

All above property are getting set except group and getting below in console log while starting service :

```
group.id = anonymous.cce5a71a-66fa-49c9-874b-09d5685713f7
```

Kindly help on this as i think because of this my consumer unable to read from where it left.
I am using Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE.

Few important dependency related to this, Also I am using Spring integration starter as well :-

```
     <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Show your consumer code - should `INPUT` be `input`?

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell , indeed this was a case of incorrect "INPUT" instead of "input" in my consumer.