# Configured group ID is ignored in spring-cloud-streams

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

## The goal

I must setup a **group id** for the kafka stream consumer, that matches a strict naming convention.

I cannot find a way that works after having followed deeply the documentation. As I still believe that I may have misundersood something, I prefer to open a question here for peer-review before opening a bug issue on spring-cloud-stream github repository.

#### NB:

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078231/unable-to-set-group-id-in-spring-cloud-stream-kafka) was already asked one year ago, but the question is not very exaustive and not answered yet, I hope that I can give more insight to the problem here.

## What the official documentation states (and also based on WARN messages)

From several sources of the official documentation, I see that this should be pretty easy to configure in `application.yaml` of my app.

The documentation states that I can either:

- use a default value for all the binders, using the section `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.group=<value>`
- or use a specific value for my channel in `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.group`

If I setup directly the kafka generic field `group-id` in `spring.kafka.consumer.group-id` the parameter is explicitely ignored and I get the following `WARN`:

```
2022-08-10 10:18:18.376 [main] [WARN ] [o.s.c.s.b.k.s.p.KafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties] - Ignoring provided value(s) for 'group.id'. Use spring.cloud.stream.default.group or spring.cloud.stream.binding.<name>.group to specify the group instead of group.id
```

so I have also tried in both the sections `spring.cloud.stream.default.group` and `spring.cloud.stream.binding.<name>.group` (note that it is stated here `binding` and not `bindings`, without `s`).

Edit: Based on a comment from @OlegZhurakousky, this is only a typo in the error message. I tested with and without the `s` without success.

### Looking at the code of the library

I have had a quick look at the stream code, and this property seems indeed the one that must be set, such as they are doing [in their tests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/3.2.x/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/bootstrap/KafkaBinderMeterRegistryTest.java#L106), we can see that they use for example: `--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.group=inputGroup` .

## The problem after following the documentation

The group ID seems always ignored, after testing all the afore mentioned configuration. The group is always set to the default value, which is `groupId=process-applicationId`.

such as in the logs as follow:

```
2022-08-10 10:30:56.644 [process-applicationId-c433e54c-2a51-4618-b7a6-14a96b252daf-StreamThread-1] [INFO ] [o.a.k.c.c.i.SubscriptionState] - [Consumer clientId=process-applicationId-c433e54c-2a51-4618-b7a6-14a96b252daf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=process-applicationId] Resetting offset for partition my-custom-topic-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}.
2022-08-10 10:32:56.713 [process-applicationId-c433e54c-2a51-4618-b7a6-14a96b252daf-StreamThread-1] [INFO ] [o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread] - stream-thread [process-applicationId-c433e54c-2a51-4618-b7a6-14a96b252daf-StreamThread-1] Processed 0 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 0 total tasks since the last update
2022-08-10 10:34:56.767 [process-applicationId-c433e54c-2a51-4618-b7a6-14a96b252daf-StreamThread-1] [INFO ] [o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread] - stream-thread [process-applicationId-c433e54c-2a51-4618-b7a6-14a96b252daf-StreamThread-1] Processed 0 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 0 total tasks since the last update
```

It is like the `application.yaml` for group is not used at all. On the other hand, the `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.destination=my-custom-topic` field that set `destination: my-custom-topic` is understood and the topic is followed correctly (see the logs above).

## How my application is setup

### relevant dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

### kakfa stream consumer class (simplified to include only the relevant sections)

```java
package my.custom.stuff;


import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Component
public class myKafkaStreamConsumer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myKafkaStreamConsumer.class);

    @Bean
    public static Consumer<KStream<String, String>> process() {
        return input ->
                input.foreach((key, value) -> {
                    logger.debug("from STREAM: Key= {} , value = {}", key, value);
                    // ...
                    // my message handling business logic
                    // ...
                });
    }
}
```

### one version of the application.yaml

I put here the version of the application.yaml that IMHO should be the most compliant with the documentation and still is not working, note that the `destination` is correctly used, so at least it is using the correct channel.

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          group: myCustomGroupId
          destination: "my-custom-topic"
```

## What I have already tested (unsuccessfully)

I have tried to inject the group id in several ways, that include:

- all the possible combinations that I could find in any official documentation or example
- adding it in the `consumer` subsection such as in `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.group` or `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.group-id`
- injecting the official documented keys as environment variables

It simply seems always ignored.

## References

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_summary_of_function_based_programming_styles_for_kafka_streams
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties

Comment: Have you tried setting the `default` group? Not the `process-in-0`?

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi , do you mean `spring.cloud.stream.default.group` ? yes I have tried

Comment: The error message you see about singular `binding` is a type that we must fix It should be plural `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.binding-name.group=hello`

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky thanks for confirming this, I though about that, but wanted to give it a try anyway

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky , I have accepted the solution from @Tim, but nontheless I think that the documentation is misleading if it states that you can use `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<name>.group` and instead you must use `applicationId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a disclaimer, I'm a bit rusty on Spring but since I've been working with Kafka for the past couple of months I wanted to play with this too.
I got it to work by doing two things:

- use `applicationId` instead of `group` within the application properties

  ```
  spring:
    kafka:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092
      consumer:
        auto-offset-reset: earliest
    cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
            functions:
              process:
                applicationId: MyGroupIdUsingApplicationId
        bindings:
          process-in-0:
            bindings:
              process-in-0:
                destination: my-custom-topic
  ```
- explicitly declare a `KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties` bean

I created a working sample here for you to clone and test with if you need to:
https://github.com/T-TK-Wan/SO-Spring_Cloud_Streams_Kafka_GroupId

Edit:

Just to add that I was focused on just seeing that the GroupId can be set and that it registers correctly, whether using the `applicationId` property is correct and what side effects there are, I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Also found this relevant post explaining why it's applicationId used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394271/unable-to-set-groupid-in-spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams3-1-1?rq=1

Comment: hello @Tim, thanks for your answer. I don't know, to me this is a sort of workaround. What if your application needs to listen on different topics, and that for each one of them the group-id must be different? For example, our client requires that the group-id naming convention also takes track of the topic that it consumes (don't ask me what my opinion about this convention is)

Comment: @Danduk82 each consumer has a group-id.
So if you have multiple functions, then you should be able to set diff group-ids I believe.
Let me have a play around.

Comment: This is also my understanding, and my problem is that the group id MUST be set explicitly in this project. For the moment I have rolled-back to use the spring-boot kafka lib instead of streams, which is a shame when you see how much more you can do with streams.

Comment: I've pushed a change if you want to check it out.

I'm not sure if i've misunderstood, but there's nothing stopping you from setting the groupId (applicationId field) to your specific value within the properties file.

```applicationId: my-custom-topic-GroupId```

With logs showing as such:

```[Consumer clientId=my-custom-topic-GroupId-5a17f930-560c-40bb-86b6-803657a86499-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-custom-topic-GroupId] ```

Comment: Indeed, but setting the value on the binder, will set this as "global" for the application. But if you want to set it on the channel (as I would have expected to be possible), to be able to set a different value for each channel (e.g in the case that you have more than one topic to listen) you loose this granularity. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Danduk82, you can configure the group-id based on each function which allows for granularity on the topics that are consumed. The terminology regarding channels and binders is not clear to me as I've not worked on the Cloud Streams lib except for just experimenting for this post. I've pushed another update to the repo, where you can see there's three different functions consuming different topics (one with multiple). Each has a separate group-id. Apologies if I haven't understood correctly.

Comment: Hello @Tim, i have tested your solution with the different group ids: it works like a charm, thanks a lot. I validate your answer.

Comment: (and the bounty)